# mobile.changePage to nextPage?

Tags: java, jquery, android, jquery-mobile

How do I change the code below to swipe to the next page/ the 'to: url' w/o having to write the script for every page change?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $('div').live("swipeleft", function(){
                $.mobile.changePage("#pg02", "slide", false, true);
            });
            $('div').live("swiperight", function(){
                $.mobile.changePage("#pg01", "slide", true, true);
            }); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

rename your pages to pg1 pg2, ..., pg10 without the zeros in front

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 window.now=1;

        $('div').live("swipeleft", function(){
            window.now++
            $.mobile.changePage("#pg"+window.now, "slide", false, true);
        });
        $('div').live("swiperight", function(){
            window.now--;
            $.mobile.changePage("#pg"+window.now, "slide", true, true);
        }); 
</script>
```

you will have to add some `if`s to guard first and last page.
You might also want to put the now variable in some other object not in the global scope of window object.

Comment: Thanx!!  I knew it had to be that simple.  I was trying something almost the same w/no luck.  Works great! Thnx again.

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too soon.  I started adding pages (after 3), and discovered the code cuases it to jump two pages at a time - Any Ideas?

Comment: this is because you have to bind the events correctly. I just used your example assuming you know what you're doing. This event fires multiple times when you swipe over a div in a div. bind it to something more unique. try `$('body').bind(` or just bind to a button